# How can I build a pre-configured distributable Raspberry Pi image?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cicd

I want to build a Raspberry Pi image configured with a customised set of packages and configuration ready to image and distribute to push onto a SD card and boot from.

i.e. I want to automate the manual process of:

1. Download Raspberry Pi image
2. 'Flash' to an SD card
3. Boot up
4. `apt update && apt install minicom`
5. `vi /etc/minicom/minirc.dfl`

...

6. Shut down Raspberry Pi
7. Save an image of the configured system
8. Upload image online

What are the most appropriate existing tools to automate such a build?

Comment: At step 7, put the SD in another machine and `dd` the entire disk and `gzip` it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I meant more in a CI/CD sense.

Answer (score 1):

The [packer-builder-arm](https://github.com/mkaczanowski/packer-builder-arm) plugin for [HashiCorp Packer](https://www.packer.io/) seems to be a good starting point. [This](https://linuxhit.com/build-a-raspberry-pi-image-packer-packer-builder-arm/) is a good initial tutorial although further thinking is required to apply customisation.

There is also [packer-plugin-arm-image](https://github.com/solo-io/packer-plugin-arm-image) which does a similar job. A explanation for why the packer-builder-arm was also developed is [documented in a pull request](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/pull/8462).

Answer (score -1):

A very simple and efficient method is to use the Linux tool
**dd** inspired by "Data Definition statement of IBM OS/360 JCL"

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 | gzip /media/rpi_card.copy.img.gz
```

If you prefer more, you can send image over the network to another host

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 | gzip -1 - | ssh user@192.168.1.1 dd of=rpi_card.copy.img.gz
```